# Databases of all Astronomical Geomagnetic storms data

Tags: solar-terrestrial-physics, storms, electromagnetism, magnetosphere

I am doing a project in which I need data from all the globe of geomagnetic storms, I need to ask that from where I can find a list of all sites where I can find the data of geomagnetic storms easily or I would manually search about database of each country which provides the data?

Comment: you will probably find a lot of what you need in the links on this page https://spaceweather.com/ or atleast make your search a bit easier.

Answer (score 2):

Could you be specific in your question as to what data you need on storms? Do you just need dates when storms occurred, or [global geomagnetic index activity levels](http://isgi.unistra.fr/), or [ground magnetic field measurements](https://intermagnet.github.io/)? Are you interested in the storm effects at Earth, or do you want space-borne measurements of solar activity?

You can find lists of some basic info for the largest storms at [spaceweatherlive.com](https://www.spaceweatherlive.com/en/auroral-activity/top-50-geomagnetic-storms.html) for example. For more detailed, or longer term lists there are [academic studies such as this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11207-016-0897-y) (which may be behind a paywall, so contact you institute library if you have one, or email the authors as they'd likely be happy to send you a copy).

Comment: I need to study effects of Geomagnetic storms on Earth objects since 1930 for which I need databases of different locations on globe so that I can cover the whole globe. I hope you understand what I want to say.

Comment: And yeah, I just need dates that when storms occurred.

Comment: @JunaidIhsan you can look in the links for the different solar cycles here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_solar_cycles this is why it is important to make the questions as clear as possible to make it easier to give you the information you seek.